# Getting NSolid Historical Data

Tags: nsolid

Does Nsolid keep historical data for hosts? When a process exits, it seems like the data for that host is gone, at lease from the UI.

Is there a way to surface historical data. If it is not possible now is this a feature to support it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) and [nsolid-statsd](https://github.com/nodesource/nsolid-statsd) to monitor [N|Solid](https://nodesource.com/products/nsolid) runtime and collect metrics.

```
npm install -g nsolid-statsd
```

Run statsd and run nsolid-statsd pointing to statsd service and to the [proxy](https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/1.2/docs/installing-the-hub)

```
nsolid-statsd localhost:8125 localhost:9000
```

You can configure statsd to store information and even integrate it with [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)

**UPDATE:**

N|Solid console store metrics, historical data, cpu profiles and heap snapshots files in a internal directory, you can override this directory using `--storage` flag. Be aware that anytime that console is restarted this directory is wipe out, is somewhat volatile. Engineering team is working hard to unify this data into a better storage mechanism that offer more flexibility.